# Как синхронизировать локальный git-репозиторий с хостингом без git?

Tags: ftp, bitbucket, git, ssh

Сайт расположен на хостинге majordomo (есть только ftp и ssh)

Основная разработка ведется на локальном веб-сервере +git.
Для совместной разработки проект выливается на bitbucket.
Чтобы обновлять проект на хостинге использую git-ftp.

Проблема в том, что при использовании git-ftp теряются файлы (при передаче).
Приходится дозаливать вручную. Постоянно слышу, что ftp - ненадежный протокол.

Локальная версия с bitbucket работают отлично, как только выливаю на хостинг
начинаются проблемы (имею ввиду git-ftp).

Правильная ли у меня схема работы?
Как можно улучшить эту схему?
Хостинг поддерживает ssh, стоит ли использовать его, и как?
прошу любых рекомендаций

Comment: Можно ли вместо git-ftp использовать ssh? (git-ftp передает только те файлы, которые были изменены, можно ли добиться того же самого используя протокол ssh?)

Comment: https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp

в моем случае (PHP) пользуюсь встроенной фичей в PHPStorm, где после коммита автоматом можно настроить заливку на указанный сервер

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да. Вы можете зайти на хостинг по ssh. И сделать там `git pull && git checkout имя_ветки`

Если не хотите настраивать там гит - тогда можно вместо ftp заливать файлы на хостинг через rsync.

Но я всё же рекомендую пользоватся именно git.

Comment: я бы с радостью настроил на хостинге git, но хостер этого не позволяет

Comment: Тогда rsync

Comment: с ним никогда не сталкивался, в чем его преимущества перед git-ftp?

Comment: А я с гит-фтп не сталкивался. Но судя по : 

>> Проблема в том, что при использовании git-ftp теряются файлы (при передаче).

в сулчае с rsync - такого нету.

примерная команда:

    rsync -av -e 'ssh' /path/to/local/dir user@remoteHostOrIp:/path/to/remote/dir

Comment: спасибо за пример команды. Подскажите еще пожалуйста как быть с игнорируемыми файлами, git-ftp учитывает .gitignore, а как быть в случае с rsync?

Comment: нужно добавить параметр: `--exclude '.*'`

в данном случае мы пропускаем все файлы, которые начинаются на .

Comment: rsync - super-быстрый и очень умный, реальной альтернативы по скорости и гибкости ему нет. По-умолчанию присутствует практические на всех хостингах. Rsync - это синхронизация, Git - синхронизация, развертывание и управление.